# Is there any filter opposite to Polarizing filter, to emphasize reflections?

Tags: filters, reflection, glare

Polarizing filters are mainly used to reduce glare on water or similar surfaces. My question is, are there any filters that do the opposite job? ie that allow the camera to capture **more glare or reflections on shiny surfaces**?

P.S. Main objective is to **increase the effect in reflection photography**. Any other advice on increasing the reflection over water surfaces would also be appreciated.

Comment: @zacharmarz: Yes, you are right. I thought that it was one cycle on a revolution, but it's actually two.

Comment: Note a physically perfect polarizing filter will remove exactly half of light. A real filter removes about just as much (leaking about as much of what it's to block, as blocking of desired polarity) so all photos with polarizing filter need about one stop "brighter" settings.

Comment: @SF. How much light a polarizing filter reduces all depends upon the orientation of the filter and the orientation of the light striking it. Your statement *assumes* that the light striking the polarizer is equally polarized in all directions. That is very rarely (as in pretty much *never*) the case.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The answer will be easy to figure out if you understand a little bit what polarization means.

I don't have a polarizing filter to play with, but I do have a physics degree, so here it goes:

Light reflected by certain types of surfaces (such as glass or water, but not metal) is partially linearly polarized.  Light reflected under a [certain angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brewster_angle) is fully polarized.

Linear polarization means that the electromagnetic wave (light) vibrates in a certain plane only, to put it simply.  If you rotate the polarization filter to align with this plane, it lets the polarized light through.  If you rotate it to orient it 90 degrees to the plane of polarization, it filters it out fully.

Sunlight will contain light of all polarizations, so a polarization filter will only filter "half of it".  Reflected light contains more of light polarized in a plane parallel to the reflecting surface: so if you align the polarization filter perpendicular to the reflecting surface, it will filter out more of the reflected light than light coming from elsewhere.  If you orient it parallel to the surface, it will filter out less of the reflected light---the effect you are looking for.

So the short answer is: just rotate the polarization filter and find the orientation which makes the reflection look the brightest! This will accentuate the reflections in the photo instead of suppressing them.

**EDIT:**  Here's an extra idea: you could take two photos, one where you minimize the intensity of the reflections and one where you maximize it.  Using these two images, you could make the reflection even stronger by subtracting some of the relfection-less image.  It'd take some experimentation with an image processing package to see if it is possible to get it right.

Comment: I think its incorrect to say that a polarizer rotated to avoid filtering out light of a given polarization will actually INCREASE the effect. It won't mitigate it, but its also not going to increase it. In other words, rotating the polarizer to *not filter out* the light being reflected is potentially just as good, but not necessarily better than, not using a polarizer at all.

Comment: @jrista: A filter can't increase light, but the polarising filter will let through 100% of the light with a specific angle, and by average 50% of the light with other angles, so it will increase the reflected light *relative* to the non-reflected light. It works as a neutral density filter for non-reflected light.

Comment: @Guffa: Again, I would dispute that anything is *increasing* at all. Something, in this case the other half of light, is being **reduced** as it doesn't fully match the polarization angle of the filter...but the reflections are not being increased. From practical experience, angling a polarizer to the primary angle of reflected light still tends to reduce the overall amount of reflection, as not every single ray of reflected light always has exactly the same polarity...especially off of water. Your almost always going to reduce reflections a little.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Your Extra Idea is stupendous. Moreover an explanation of Circular Porlarization in your post would be welcome.

Comment: @jrista Everything in photography is relative. Theoretically speaking, not filtering out the reflections whilst filtering out 50% non reflected light will *increase* the **relative** strength of the reflections. In practice results will vary as the reflections are not entirely polarized the unreflected light may be partially polarized by the atmosphere.

Comment: @jrista As others mentioned, a polarizing filter will definitely reduce the intensity of non-polarized light.  Whether this 1/2 decrease is clearly visible or not, I am not sure.  You may be right that it isn't (an 1/2 decrease could be quite small on a logarithmic scale, and our perception is said to be approximately logarithmic).  If would be interesting to see a comparison photo, as I said unfortunately I don't have a polarizing filter to try this out in practice ... all of this was just theory.

Comment: @Skippy I tried this idea with two photos I got from the internet, but unfortunately it didn't work so well because I couldn't align the two images well enough.  It might work better on high resolution images (I tried it on very small ones). I don't have a polarizing filter to do the experiment properly :(

Comment: I think everyone is missing my point. Sure, your going to reduce a lot of the other, random light scattered through the atmosphere, kind of like an ND filter. Thats just going to reduce light overall. When it comes to reflections, more so on water than on glass, water does not reflect light at the same angle, so it polarizes at a lot of angles. If you align a polarizer to one particular angle of light being reflected off of water, your still going to filter out some of that polarized light. From the standpoint of REFLECTIONS, I don't think using an aligned polarizer is better...

Comment: ...than not using a polarizer at all. I think a polarizer, when photographing water, is going to reduce some of the **reflections** to a certain degree. The OP wants **more** glare and reflections, not less. On a relative basis, you might darken the scene relative to reflected light, but the best approach is to do what Matt Grum stated in his answer...reduce the angle of incidence, which will increase the amount of reflection **in reality.** This answer has received a lot of up votes, possibly because of my argument, but Matt's answer is the correct one.

Comment: @jrista: You seem confused about how a polarization works. The reflected light will be partially polarized. The polarizer will attenuate all light. The non polarized light from the background will be attenuated by roughly 2 stops (only an ideal polarizer costs only one stop), but the partially polarized light of the reflection will be attenuated **less** than the background. There is physically no way the reflection can be attenuated more than the background, unless you orient the polarizer the other way around.

Comment: @EdgarBonet: I know exactly how polarization works. The polarization angle of reflected light is dependent upon the angle at which it is reflected. From glass, you might get a unified result, where reflected light is polarized at roughly the same angle, although even with glass there the surface is not perfectly flat. With water, however, you tend to have a very uneven surface, and reflected light will NOT all have exactly the same polarization. Most of it will be polarized such that if you align a polarizer to allow reflections through, most reflections will remain.

Comment: But **not** all reflected light will fall within the narrow "window" and be completely allowed through buy a polarizer (angle of reflectance off of water could vary quite a lot depending on how active the water surface is), and some of it will get filtered, at least partially. The question asked how to INCREASE reflections, which is different than simply accentuating reflections. You can accentuate reflections in post if thats what your after, and its a lot easier to do. A polarizer will *not* actually increase reflections...i.e. there is no actual "inverse polarizer" as the OP requested.

Comment: I'm not arguing against the fact that you **can** *accentuate* reflections by essentially doing the opposite of what you would normally do to reduce them. I'm arguing that doing so does not actually answer the question asked. The *EDIT* to this question is actually a better answer than simply inverse-orienting the polarizer. Matt Grum's answer, to reduce the angle of incidence, is also another great solution to the problem.

Comment: @jrista: Please explain what you mean by _increase_ reflections, and what you mean by _accentuate_ reflections. And in what way the two things are different.

Comment: Let us take this from a different angle: If you want to objectively INCREASE reflections, you set your camera one stop higher and then you increase ALL of the image, highlights, mattes, shadows, EVERYTHING - including reflections. With a polarizing filter you still have the camera take the photo one step higher(!!!) but then all non-reflections are dimmed. With the filter you first increase the reflections (and everything else) by taking a photo one step higher, then dim everything else than the reflections back down using the filter.

Comment: @jrista Arguing that reflections on water as opposed to glass are going all over the place only makes sense for seriously disturbed water.  But then there aren't as much identifiable reflections as there is a glare pattern showcasing the form of the water surface.  For accentuating a glare pattern, the strongest effect will be from blocking the polarisation direction corresponding to a straightforward reflection.  But for calm water with a clearly visible reflection (at Brewster's angle), you want to maximise the relative strength of the polarised reflection against the unpolarised backdrop.

Comment: @jrista -- you're right that filters only reduce intensity. But when we say that the filter increases something, we're talking about the final image, which we get by reducing some of the light with the filter **and** increasing the light with a wider aperture or longer exposure. So whatever the filter transmits gets increased in the image. It's the image that's important.

Answer (score 11):

> Any Other advice on increasing the reflection over water surfaces.

Specular reflections like you get from water are stronger the lower the angle of incidence. This means when the light is coming almost parallel to the surface and striking a glancing blow.

This is easy to achieve under controlled lighting. In natural light this means waiting until the sun is low in the sky like at sunrise or sunset.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you use a polarising filter for that too.

At a specific angle the polarising filter will let through 0% of the reflected light, and 50% of the rest of the light.

Turned 90 degrees the filter will let through 100% of the reflected light, and 50% of the rest of the light.

Comment: You mean ninety degrees, not 180 degrees.

Comment: @StaaleS: I meant 180 degrees, i.e. turning the filter half a revolution, but checking what the filter does, there is two cycles on a revolution, so you are right, it's 90 degrees.

Comment: stating the obvious: won't work with circular filters

Comment: @Baczek: Why wouldn't it? The only difference is that the circular filter has a de-polariser behind the polariser filter.

Comment: @Baczek: You are wrong. Circular filters only randomize the incoming (polarized) light after it has already passed through a perfectly standard linear polarizing layer at the front of the filter. This has no visible effect but ensures that the light exiting the filter is for all practical purposes randomly polarized so that the autofocus mechanism in the camera can do its thing. The linear polarizing layer at front still does what it always did.

Comment: i stand corrected. for some reason i thought that circular filters are polarized, well, circularly.

Comment: @Baczek: A circular polarizer filters light according to its linear polarization (like a standard polarizer), then converts this polarization into a circular polarization (not a random polarization as Staale S says). Thus, you really get circular polarized light out of the filter.

Comment: More precisely: The confusion comes from mixing up the photography sense and the physics sense of the word "circular polarity". A camera circular filter should be correctly named "a bundled pair of polarizing filters: linear and circular" but that's obviously an unwieldy name and since no pure circular polarization is used in photography, the popular bundle hijacked the name, and sows confusion in all with background in physics who come into photography.

Comment: @SF.: Both linear and circular is used in an illogical way for polarising filters, as the terms doesn't mean at all what they do in other circumstances. Most polarising filters are actually both linear (i.e. having an output proportional to the input), and circular (i.e. in the shape of a circle). A linear polarising filter should just be called a polarising filter, and a circular polarising filter should be called something like a de-polarised polarising filter, but correct naming doesn't help you to understand what they do unless you understand the advanced optics involved.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the most reliable way of turning the filter by 90 degrees (from the rather well-defined total blockage position) is not turning the filter by 90 degrees but turning the camera by 90 degrees.  That is, for a shot in landscape, first achieve maximal blockage by rotating the filter while in in portrait mode and then turn the camera to take the shot, and vice versa.

Comment: @SF "A camera circular filter should be correctly named "a bundled pair of polarizing filters: linear and circular": nope, that's incorrect since it's a linear _polarizing_ filter and a quarter wave plane.  The polarizing filter _picks_ a polarization direction, but the quarter wave plane _retards_ part of the polarised light.  Of course "quarterwave" is a euphemism for anything but one specific wavelength but it tends to be close enough for measuring purposes (autofocus, film TTL, film metering).