# Emphasise reflections

Tags: shooting-technique, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any filter opposite to Polarizing filter, to emphasize reflections?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/26067/is-there-any-filter-opposite-to-polarizing-filter-to-emphasize-reflections)

I know that a circular polariser can reduce reflections from reflective surfaces. I'm however looking for a way to increase those reflections such that they become dominant in the picture.

An example would be a window where the sky reflects in but where the inside of the building is also visible. I want to minimise the visibility of the interior and emphasise the reflected sky.

What methods exist to emphasise reflections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a polarizer, adjusting its wheel in the position that visually makes the reflections strongest; the result is an image with stronger reflections than those that you would see without the polarizer itself.